# I need an infinite argument C# string

Tags: c#, .net, string

so I need to create an infinite (or at least 1000) argument string. I just need to be able to hard code 1000 arguments.

I have tried `var I = new List<string>("bob", "frank",` and so on to 1000 arguments); and I can't find a way in C# so if I need a NuGet package thats fine.

Comment: Welcome back. Can I ask what the problem is that you're trying to solve? Not that you need 1000 strings, I mean what is it you're doing that you need the 1000 strings for? You may be suffering from the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: you could use list initializer instead of constructor aka either new List<string>() {"bob", "frank", ...} or if it's fixed you can go for array instead new[] {"bob", "frank", ...}

Comment: well I need a list of words in a string I can call on in an if statement

Comment: Any list of any strings? What do you mean "call on in an if statement"? Any variable within scope can be used in an if statement, that's not special for any kind of `List`. Again, what is the problem you're trying to solve with a list of strings (i.e. what is the purpose of the program you're trying to make)?

Comment: I'm a little confused by you saying that you don't need to add it in the program. As I understand it, you need a list of strings, that contains at least 1000 elements, and those will be hard coded in the program? Is this right? Or do you need to generate 1000 or more values, and stick them in a file that your program loads? A `List<String>` should have no issue holding that many elements. Can you post what error messages you're getting please?

Comment: yes this is right

Comment: @thecodingblobfish what is the purpose of this program?

Comment: So my program creates 10 randome numbers between 1 and 26. Then turns them into letters (1 = a 2 = b ...) then in those it looks for words wich is where the list comes in. The list holdes 1000 words it will look for in the randome letters and it will do it over and over until it gets a word.

Comment: the error I am getting from var I = new List<string>("bob", "frank",...); is "does not contain a constructor that takes 1000 arguments" I do not understand this

Comment: You are not instantiating the `List<string>` properly. You can't just keep putting strings in the constructor, you have 3 options: 1) empty constructor (`new List<string>()`), 2) specify a capacity (`new List<string>(1000)`), or 3) pass in an existing `IEnumerable` object (do not use this one, it is pointless for your case).

Comment: I am confused what would the second one do?

Comment: The second one will decrease the memory usage of the `List<string>` slightly, but likely not noticeably for your case. It might be good to be in the habit of specifying a capacity if you know what it will be, though.

Comment: so what would be the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, asking someone to provide the full code without attempting yourself is frowned upon, but since you mentioned in a previous question today that you were 11, take this a learning opportunity for a few different concepts.

You'll need this at the top of your .cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

And try something like this:

```
public string GenerateOutput()
{
    // create a List of 1000 words
    var words = new List<string>(1000)
    {
        "bob",
        "frank",
        "windows",
        "test",
        "sample",
        "xylophone"
        // keep populating your list of words this way
    };
    
    int numberOfLettersToGet = 10;

    // keep getting #'numberOfLettersToGet' random letters until a word is found
    char[] randomLetters = new char[numberOfLettersToGet];
    dynamic match = null;
    while (match == null)
    {
        // select 10 random letters
        randomLetters = GetRandomLetters(numberOfLettersToGet);
        
        // get the word that has the most number of matching letters
        match = words.Select(w => new { Word = w, NumberOfMatchingLetters = w.ToCharArray().Intersect(randomLetters).Count() })
                     .OrderByDescending(o => o.NumberOfMatchingLetters)
                     .FirstOrDefault(o => o.NumberOfMatchingLetters > 0);
    }
    
    // return the results
    return $"{string.Join("", randomLetters)}: found \"{match.Word}\", {match.NumberOfMatchingLetters} matching letters";
}

public char[] GetRandomLetters(int numberOfLetters)
{
    // create an array of letters
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
    
    // select random letters
    var rnd = new Random();
    var randomLetters = new char[numberOfLetters];
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfLetters; i++)
    {
        randomLetters[i] = letters[rnd.Next(0, numberOfLetters)];
    }
    
    return randomLetters;
}
```

Here is a fiddle you can play around with: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GNE96w